# why I can't use props properties in useEffect function?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am learning react js and I am novice in web development.

The error is that the `useEffect` function can't read properties of props passed however I can use it outside the `useEffect` function.

> **TypeError:** *Cannot read property 'id' of null*

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    let isMounted = true;
    NotificatioDataService.retieveNotificationByDoctorId(props.currentUser.id)
    .then(response => {
      if (isMounted){
      var x =0;
      response.data.map((item)=>{
        console.log("x", x = x+1);
        console.log(item)
      });
      setCount(x)
    }})
    return () => { isMounted = false };
  },[])
```

I am using `useEffect` to return the number of notifications in database
The origin of currentUser variable is in *App.js* file  :

```
<Route path="/DoctorDrawer" render={(props) => <DoctorDrawer authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUser={this.state.currentUser} {...props} />}></Route>
```

- The useEffect function is a part of *DoctorDrawer* component

---

**Update**

I think that the problem is that the use effect in called twice however I don't know what is the origin of the the first call. all the useEffects in all component are called twice and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Didn't you forget to add `this.` before `props`?

Comment: Can you post the whole component's code? Using the props should work.

Comment: @Alexander as this is a function component, there should be no `this.`

Comment: the same errorr Alexander

Comment: I assume that `props.currentUser` is populated asynchronously by a component higher up the tree but you are still rendering this component before `props.currentUser` has been populated. This means that `props.currentUser` will not have a value hence the "Cannot read property 'id' of null". Either wait for the data to load before rendering the component at all or add a check to the `useEffect` to ensure that the user is populated and add the user to the `useEffect`s dependency array.

Comment: @Alexander By default, you know it's a functional component because OP is using a hook. No need for `this.`

Comment: @JacobSmit Sorryy, I didn't understand you but I remember that useEffect is called twice in normal cases and when I passed a parametre inside useEffect function the error is happened . I hope you will understand me. I don't speak english fluently btw

Comment: props.currentUser should likely be provided in input array [], do a check inside if it's truthy before accessing it. *when I passed a parametre inside useEffect function the error is happened* - are you saying that you're able to access id outside useEffect? Any way, you need to provide all code that is needed to reproduce the problem, especially the origin of currentUser, the snippet doesn't make sense alone.

Comment: @EstusFlask You are right I will edit my question post above

Comment: @EstusFlask  I edit the post I hope it's clear now

Comment: could you try this `props.currentUser?.id`

Comment: @miraj failek to compile with error :  _unexpected token_

Comment: I think that @JacobSmit comment is interesting because like I sad when I console.log a useEffect or componenetDidMount result I note that that function is called twice, but I don't know how to resolve what jacob sad

Comment: Here is a rough example of an `App` component loading a user object and then passing it to a component (`Example`) in a `Route`. The `Example` component then loads further data once the user has been loaded by the `App`. Checking the console each async request should only be called once. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x4bhs8

Comment: thank you so much @JacobSmit, I will try so much to understand the example you send